# MySQL Connector C++ Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project in VS 2013 Community Edition. It uses MySQL Connector C++. Here's some code:

Database.cpp:

```
#include "Database.h"
#include "Common.h"
#include <iostream>

//This function is used to connect to the MySQL database
void Database::Connect()
{

    Config::loadConfig("config.ini");
    MySQLSettings settings = Config::getMySQLSettings();

    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;

    //Creates a connection to your MySQL server
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://" + settings.host + ":3306", settings.username, settings.password);
    //Connect to LUR database
    con->setSchema(settings.database);
}
```

Database.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

class Database
{
public:
    static void Connect(); //Database connection function
};
```

With that code, I get these errors:

```
1>Database.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__get_driver_instance
1>Database.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>Database.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ)
1>C:\Users\anon\Desktop\lurebornserver\Source\Release\LURServer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the source for the MySQL Connector C++.
2. Add the *Preprocessor Definition* `CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=`
3. Configure the MySQL Connector (You may need to download CMake)
4. Build the MySQL Connector.

Remember to add the *Preprocessor Definition* `CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=` to all files that use the MySQL Connector.

You will also need to download MySQL source and build that as well.

Rebuilding the sources will ensure compatibility with your compiler and platform to the MySQL Server and Connector.